# Differential equation where rate is $\propto x^2$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I was wondering if someone could tell me where I'm going wrong with my word problem.

The question is:

The rate at which a salt dissolves is approximately equal to the square of its mass. The starting mass is 35 grams. $ y(7)=13.2$. How much of the salt is left after 11 minutes?

My effort is:

I've set up the equation as   $y'=(35-x)k$ and get the right solution but I don't know how to proceed when its asking the rate is the square of the mass.

Thanks.

Comment: I think that $y'$ should become a $y^2$. Isn't $y$ the mass and isn't $y'$ the rate at which the mass changes?

Answer (score 0):

I believe we are missing something in the statement of the problem. 
I think (as you have stated the question) we need to solve something like this

$$ y'(x)=y^2, \\y(0)=35, \\ y(7)=13.2$$

So then we can solve the [diff eq](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27(x)%3Dy%5E2) and compute the constants.

$$ y(x)=\frac{1}{c_1-x}$$

Does this mean that $c_1=1/35$? but now how will we include this second point? 
I'm not quite sure yet.

What if we interpreted the line as the rate salt dissolves is approximately ***proportional*** to the square of its mass. Then maybe we could look at it like this?

$$ y'(x)=cy^2, \\y(0)=35, \\ y(7)=13.2$$

Then we should be able to [solve this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27(x)%3Dcy%5E2) for

$$y(x)=\frac{1}{k_1-cx}$$

Then we could solve for $k_1=1/35$ and $c$.

Comment: I think I made a mistake with the y(0)= 35 as those boundary conditions weren't included in the original question. But your suggestion does provide an answer. I did use the boundary condition y(0)=(0) to solve for C.  I'm also confused... am I setting this equation for the dissolved matter or what is left?

Comment: I think that the last step would be: 
Now that you have $y(x)$  you want to compute $y(11)$.

Comment: I think Ross Millikan's answer uses "$-k$" which seems to be an intuitive way of interpreting "dissolves" but I don't think it much matters because this will roll into the constant I called "$c$"

Comment: Since the question says the rate of dissolution is approximately proportional to the square mass, it would imply the population of the solute is increasing, so k would be positive right?

Comment: @persimonns:  no dissolving means the undissolved mass of salt is decreasing.  Note that you start with $35$ grams and after $7$ minutes you have $13.2$

Comment: @persimonns. Yes in Millikan's answer k is positive. I think I am confused by your question. It's true that $k$ is positive. I am not sure what is meant by the "population " of the solute. I wouldn't describe salt as a population. The truth is I think your question matters little. If you have set up the diff eq as Millikan or I have done and then put in those conditions we are in good shape. As in we'll compute a $y(x)$ that correctly computes the amount of undissolved salt after x minutes.  Then you plug in values to finish the job.

Answer (score 0):

When you are told the rate of change is equal to the square of its mass, there has to be a constant because the units don't match.  It would be better to say the rate of change of the mass is proportional to the square of the mass.

Using $y$ for the mass of the block we have 
$$y'=-ky^2\\\frac 1y=C+kt$$
Now we can plug the data in to evaluate $C,k$
$$y(0)=35\\C=\frac1{35}\\y(7)=13.2\\\frac 1{13.2}=\frac1{35}+7k\\k=\frac 17\left(\frac 1{13.2}-\frac 1{35}\right)\approx 0.00674\\
y(11)\approx\frac 1{0.00674\cdot 11+\frac 1{35}}\approx 9.735$$

Comment: @Mason:  It just changes the sign of $k$.  I find it easier to make $k$ positive when possible.

Comment: @Mason:  you need the constant $k$ to have enough freedom to fit the data.  It is not clear to me how $y(x)=\frac 1{c_1-x}$ becomes $y(x)=\frac 1{k_1-cx}$ or what $k_1,c$ are.

Comment: Thanks guys I'm gonna retry this problem with the new knowledge.